# How to set year limit in MaterialDatePicker dialog Android Studio

Tags: android, material-ui, material-design, material-components-android, materialdatepicker

I'm having trouble set max. and min. years in Material Design Datepickerdialog, also put an image of the Material Date picker dialog box where only one year is being shown.

**Below is Code**

```
    long today = MaterialDatePicker.todayInUtcMilliseconds();
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());

              calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JANUARY);
              long jan = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
                calendar.setTimeInMillis(today);


             int lastMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, lastMonth);
                long dec = calendar.getTimeInMillis();


        CalendarConstraints.Builder calendarConstraintBuilder = new CalendarConstraints.Builder();
        calendarConstraintBuilder.setValidator(DateValidatorPointBackward.now());
        calendarConstraintBuilder.setStart(jan);
        calendarConstraintBuilder.setEnd(dec);

        MaterialDatePicker.Builder<Long> materialBuilder = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker();
        materialBuilder.setTitleText("Select Date Of Birth");
        materialBuilder.setSelection(today);


        materialBuilder.setCalendarConstraints(calendarConstraintBuilder.build());



        final MaterialDatePicker<Long> materialDatePicker = materialBuilder.build();
        inputEditTextDateOfBirth.setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false);
```

[image]

Comment: What is your expected result because it looks like you are getting exactly what you coded.

Comment: I want to show years  from recent years to till 2000.

Answer (score 3):

For other readers, note that this problem pertains to the year selection after clicking on the month-year widget.

For year range selection purposes you have a line missing:

```
    // set minimum year variable
    int minYear = 2010;

    // here you set the month using the "current" calendar instance
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JANUARY);

    // but you need to also set the year of "min"
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, minYear);

    // and then get a snapshot of that time.
    long jan = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
```

I'm not sure if that completely satisfies your requirements but at a minimum it presents a range of years.  The display of text was part of my test driver using `addOnPositiveButtonClickListener`:

[image]

And as I was curious, this also prevents the "month selector arrows" from advancing earlier than "min":

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It's working . I wanted the same solution as you mentioned above.